# C++ syntax error. Missing a semi colon before a curly bracket on line 37

Tags: c++, syntax

I was creating a simple C++ console game where you can input a bunch of commands, make money and buy things. As I was coding in the first few commands, I'm getting an error saying that I'm missing a ";" before "}" on line 37. I've ended every line with a semi colon, I don't seem to get the problem. I've put asterisks on line 37. Here's my code:

```
using namespace std;

void starting() {
cout << "***********DANK MEMER***********" << endl;
cout << "Enter Your Command: ";
}

int main()

{

starting();
int balance = 0;
bool hasShovel = false;
string command;

do {
    
    cin >> command;


    // /help
    if (command == "/help") {
        cout << "The list of commands are \n /buy shovel \n /buy lawnmower \n /sell 
shovel \n /sell lawnbower \n /luck \n \n /exit /rob \n /balance \n /invest \n /dig \n 
/mow" << endl;
    }

    // buy shovel
    else if (command == "/buy shovel") {

        // checking if they have enough balance
        if (balance > 100) {
            cout << "You don't have enough to buy a shovel. It costs 100 memers." << 
endl;
        }
*****************************************
        // giving them the shovel
        else {
            balance -= 100;
            hasShovel = true;
            cout << "You have a shovel now. Happy digging!" << endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "BRUH! Not a valid command";
    }
} while (command != "/exit");


}
```

Comment: Which is line 37?

Comment: The one after 36. But now we have a new problem. What line is 36?

Comment: i put asterisks on line 37

Comment: The asterisks are on the line 37, thus that line is 38 now?

Comment: @ComplexJS Do not use asterisks.  The `*` character in C++ has specific meanings, and using that to highlight lines may cause confusion.  Second, [the code you posted has a lot of errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b97fb0b634d5b01d).

Comment: But seriously, C++ doesn't allow the broken-up string in the `if (command == "/help")` body.

Comment: can you elaborate. What will I have to change to fix the problem?

Comment: Change `cin >> command;` to `getline(cin, command);` so your `"/buy shovel"` will work.

Comment: It's all one line. Idk why it looks different on stack overflow

Comment: @ComplexJS -- *It's all one line.* -- Did you address the other issues with the code you posted?  Like the missing header files?

Comment: Did you run the code through an autoformatter that may have inserted bogus line endings before posting the question here?

Comment: Elijay. It just gives another error saying that getLine is not identified

Comment: I didn't run the code through anything. I copy pasted it from visual studio.

Comment: @ComplexJS *I copy pasted it from visual studio.* -- Did you leave out the header files when you did the copy?  If you did, why did you do that?  Missing header files is one big reason why compilation will fail.

Comment: @ComplexJS Once the missing headers are added, and that line of code you are claiming is on a single line is fixed, [there are no compilation errors when compiling with the Visual C++ compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/W67Ye779T).  This is why when you copy/paste code, you paste the entire code.  We have no idea if adding the missing headers is the issue, or whether you actually did not specify the headers, etc.  If indeed what you posted is the *entire* code that you are compiling, then the obvious reason for the compilation issues are the missing `#include` files.

Answer (score 2):

Running the code in https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler reveals the problem. There is a new line within your literal string in line 24. Newlines sometimes cause trouble, if they are unescaped (\).

Try it like this:

```
if (command == "/help") {
        cout << "The list of commands are \n /buy shovel \n /buy lawnmower\n"
        "/sell shovel\n"
        "/sell lawnbower\n"
        "/luck \n \n"
        "/exit /rob \n"
        "/balance \n"
        "/invest \n"
        "/dig \n" 
"/mow" << endl;
```

The preprocessor will concatenate the single string segments without any spaces, but that's what the `\n` are for.

This code compiles just fine for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void starting() {
cout << "***********DANK MEMER***********" << endl;
cout << "Enter Your Command: ";
}

int main()

{

    starting();
    int balance = 0;
    bool hasShovel = false;
    string command;
    
    do {
        
        cin >> command;
    
    
        // /help
        if (command == "/help") {
                cout << "The list of commands are \n /buy shovel \n /buy lawnmower\n"
                "/sell shovel\n"
                "/sell lawnbower\n"
                "/luck \n \n"
                "/exit /rob \n"
                "/balance \n"
                "/invest \n"
                "/dig \n" 
            "/mow" << endl;
        }
    
        // buy shovel
        else if (command == "/buy shovel") {
    
            // checking if they have enough balance
            if (balance > 100) {
                cout << "You don't have enough to buy a shovel. It costs 100 memers." << endl;
            }
    
            // giving them the shovel
            else {
                balance -= 100;
                hasShovel = true;
                cout << "You have a shovel now. Happy digging!" << endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "BRUH! Not a valid command";
        }
    } while (command != "/exit");
}
```

Comment: I implemented ur solution. It didnt work

Comment: @ComplexJS, I posted the complete code I've run through the online compiler.

Comment: Please note that this code is NOT geared towards 'does what you want'. There's at least one more error in there, though it is of logical and not of syntactical nature. Hint: Look at the price tag comparison of that shovel.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium You are missing `#include <string>`.  Thus this may not even compile for Visual C++, which the OP says is being used (not g++).

Comment: Let's just pop that in there.